Import custom message, module not found [ROS1]
I'm trying to import a custom message type to use in a basic publisher. The custom message file is located at /home/username/catkin_ws/src/ee106s24/msg
My import statement in publisher.py is from ee106s24.msg import EE106lab_custom_new.
Running rosrun ee106s24 publisher.py gives me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/username/catkin_ws/src/ee106s24/src/publisher.py", line 5, in <module>
from ee106s24.msg import EE106lab_custom_new
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ee106s24'
I don't know if my import statement is wrong, or I'm using catkin_make in the wrong directory or not sourcing something correctly.
Here is my CMakeList:
project(ee106s24)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
   FILES
  EE106lab_custom_new.msg
)

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs
# )


###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
   #INCLUDE_DIRS include
   #LIBRARIES 
   #ee106s24
   CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy std_msgs
  # DEPENDS system_lib
   message_generation

)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


```


The generate_messages() call is commented out. This means the messages are not generated. Uncomment it and it should work.
